# Looking up a RoleArn that is attached to a Cognito Group

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am attempting to grab the Policy document for a Users groups to look up custom Statements, but I am not sure how to do this.

I can grab the users group via the `id.jwtToken`, and I can look up that users group and get the associated `RoleArn`, but I cant seem to find someway to look up the `RoleArn` and pull back the policy document.

One possible way is to tap into the [`AWS.IAM`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/IAM.html) and set it up that way, then I could call [`getGroupPolicy`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/IAM.html#getGroupPolicy-property) to grab the `Policy Document`, but I am not sure how to set up the `IAM` constructor for this.

So the actually ask a question:

- Can I use `AWS.Cognito` to look up a groups policy document? If so, how?
- If not, how do I correctly set up the `AWS.IAM` constructor in `JavaScript`?

Thank you!

Comment: What options are you passing to `AWS.Cognito` constructor? It should include AWS credentials. Pass those credentials to `AWS.IAM` contructor (assuming they have the necessary permissions) and call [`AWS.IAM.getRolePolicy()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/IAM.html#getRolePolicy-property)

Comment: @Unsigned Apparently I wasn't using `AWS.Cognito` but rather the trimmed down `AWSCognito` and therefore had no credentials passed. But I edited accordingly and can now access it. If you post as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passing credentials to the `AWS.Cognito` constructor. Assuming those credentials have the necessary permissions, pass them to the `AWS.IAM` contructor and call [`AWS.IAM.getRolePolicy()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/IAM.html#getRolePolicy-property)